# Which options are required to send a PAC file URL via DHCP to Android devices?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp, android, pac

I would like the Android devices which connect to WiFi networks to be automatically configured to proxy their HTTP(S) traffic through a web proxy.

There is a PAC file available though an URL, which points to a `squid` proxy.

The PAC URL manually configured via `Advanced Options - Automatic Configuration` on Android devices works fine: the web traffic is correctly proxified.

I tried to send this PAC configuration via the DHCP server (`ISC`) by adding

```
option auto-proxy-config code 252 = text;
option auto-proxy-config  "http://10.10.10.254:81.pac";
```

to its configuration file but the Android devices do not take this setting into account. The setting is correctly sent by the DHCP server as part of its `DHCP Offer` packet (checked with Wireshark).

**Is there something specific to configure on the DHCP server for Android devices or does this approach does not work with them?**

Comment: AFAIK, and as far as I can tell from Google searches, Android simply doesn't support WPAD, and doesn't even entirely support manually configured PAC files.  The only exception appears to be with a particular browser that can be installed.

Comment: There are 2 proxy auto-detection mechanisms.  One uses DHCP option 252, and the other uses DNS.  In the second case, the name "WPAD" is looked up, and if this resolves, the client connects to that IP on port 80 (no option to change this) and requests /wpad.dat (no option to change this either).  So, you can get a URL that works for both by setting up DNS for the name WPAD, and making the URL http://WPAD/wpad.dat fetch the script.